# I want to change the true or false colors with jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to change the true or false colors, asp.net web form in repeater.

i did this but now working

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
            var a = document.getElementsByClassName("badge").innerHTML;
            var b = "true"

            if (a == "true") {
                $(".badge").addClass("badge bg-green");
            }
            else {
                $(".badge").addClass("badge bg-red");
            }
        });



       <td style="width: 60px">
          <p id="dik" class="badge"><%# Eval("Aktif") %></p>
       </td>
```

Comment: because ByClassName there will be return an array  , if you agree with this use index number                                                                                   var a = document.getElementsByClassName("badge")[0].innerHTML;

Comment: I have tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
       $(".badge").each(function(i,v){

            var b = "true"; // don't know use of it

            if ($(v).text() == "true") {
                $(v).addClass("badge bg-green");
            }
            else {
                $(v).addClass("badge bg-red");
            }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there would be more than one `<td>` holding badges you can try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //loop through all badges one by one
    $(".badge").each(function(){
        var a = $.trim($(this).text()); //get the p tag's text and trim it to remove spaces if any
        if (a == "true") {
            $(this).addClass("badge bg-green");
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass("badge bg-red");
        }
    });

});
```